# drupal 7 : how to active parent menu when the child menu was active?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Q: drupal 7 : how to active parent menu when the child menu was active?

Status : I'm using the nice menu module. I want to active parent menus when the child menu was active. I didn't change any code of original. how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the alternative for nice menu, [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish). Superfish gives active-trail class to menu parent when it has an active child.

Comment: You have to edit the Superfish settings on the block configuration to achieve this.